# Notification sent from the Firebase console does not work when App is in Background

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

I was able to send the notification to a single iOS device yesterday.  Today when I was sending to the same device, I received the notification when App was in foreground. What I found out was that Google changed the notification Payload. Yesterday there was the `aps` key because of which notifications were working when the app was in background/terminated. Today I found that Google removed the key `aps` altogether and replaced it with their notification payload format. `notification` is the key they are using and because of this I am not being able to read any notification when the app is in background/terminated. 
Anybody else facing a similar issue?

Comment: To be clear you sent the same request yesterday and today, and yesterday there was an aps key and today there is a notification key? Could you add your request to the question?

Comment: @ArthurThompson I went through the developers forum of Apple and it seems that didRegisterForRemoteNotifications wasn't working in SandBox mode and worked only in Production. `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` is where I register the deviceToken with firebase. Since that wasn't happening, Firebase was sending payload with `notification` key. Today Apple fixed the issue and now I am able to send notifications.

Comment: * `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

Comment: Yeah I've seen that there was an issue there. I'm happy it is working for you now.